# Issue Image Upload to Azure Blog using Nativescript Core

Tags: azure, nativescript

I am using Nativescript 4.2.0 and trying to upload an image from a local image to Azure Blob storage.

Most approaches recommended use the nativescript-background-http plugin. However by including this plugin, there are errors that start coming up requiring other npm modules. I haven't seen this reported anywhere, so I am unsure if I am doing something wrong or there are any other commands to run beside

```
tns install nativescript-background-http
```

The other plugin "nativescript-azure-storage" seems to work fine. This requires us to base64 encode our images. After Base64 encoding, the image gets uploaded to Azure Storage. However, since the image is now base64 encoded, it can't be used directly in .

Code used:

```
        const azureNSStorage = new nsAzureStorage.NativeScriptAzureStorage(config.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
        let path = selected.android;

        const imageFromLocalFile = imageSourceModule.fromFile(path);

       let base64string = imageFromLocalFile.toBase64String('png');

       azureNSStorage.uploadBlob(mycontainer, blobName, 
       base64string)
       .then(() => alert(`Uploaded successfuly`))
       .catch((err) => alert(`Error uploading: ${err}`));
```

What is the recommended way to upload images on Azure Blob so that we can reference them back in Nativescript page?

Cheers
Abhishek

Comment: can you share the errors that your are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what you need or what your backend / service provider supports. So until azure works for you as expected, there is nothing wrong with converting the image into base64 string.

Between `nativescript-background-http` should work too, let's know what are the errors you are facing here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample. For Azure Blob does not accept base 64 string. You need to send the stream. https://baskarrao.wordpress.com/2018/10/12/day-3-nativescript-post-series/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link Baskar. Your post is very insightful. We tried to use nativescript-background-http but have received errors during deploy on the phone. The app seems to be missing a lot of dependencies.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting with background http? You can create an issue against NativeScript background http repo!